# Is this the ATF drain plug on 06 Ford Fusion (please confirm)?

Tags: ford, transmission, fusion, transmission-fluid

2006 Ford Fusion SE Auto. I have it jacked up now ready to do a drain and fill of the ATF fluid but I'm not 100% sure about the drain plug. If you know this car please confirm, is this it in the pic? The plug faces to the rear not down.[image: ATF drain plug?]

Comment: OK, after some more searches I'm convinced that's the oil plug. So where is the ATF plug on this model?

Comment: Found it, will answer with pics when done!

Comment: That is indeed the engine oil drain plug. That leak is significant and needs to be repaired.

Comment: @FredWilson Do you think I just need a new plug?

Comment: Unlikely that a new plug is needed. I would try a new gasket first. While you have the plug out look for any damage to the gasket surfaces. The angle is a bit off to tell for sure but l do not see a gasket.

Answer (score 5):

The drain plug will be part of the housing of the transmission. This is the closest image I could find:

[image: 07 Ford Fusion 6 speed auto]

Note this is not exactly for your car, it's for an '07 Fusion 6 speed auto transmission. So it's not exactly correct, but I'm hoping that the '06 and '07 are close enough that this gets you into the right area.

The pic and any other info you might want to gain is here:

http://www.bobistheoilguy.com/forums/ubbthreads.php/topics/2542869/Ford_Fusion_6_speed_auto_drain

This is generally a reliable site for information, but it's a forum for that site, so your mileage may vary..

The car is front wheel drive, so you're going to be looking for the plug on the very bottom of a casing that's going to have the half shafts coming out of it. Look carefully, and you can always post an edit with pics of what you find for confirmation.

Comment: At least you found it, so that's a good thing. If your memory is as spotty as mine can be, you might want to take pics to remind yourself for the next time. Works great all the times I've done that. Especially for things like finding oil leaks that creep, and hard to locate parts.

Comment: Yea, glad I did this, I had no idea what my engine oil plug looked like. A shop told me a tranny flush was needed but I didn't want to risk backwash issues, so I decided drain and fill is sufficient (already over 200k on odo) plus I saved $165 possibly more.